Outlier Detection for non linear data for regression
I am grappling with two parameters exhibiting an 82% correlation, showcasing a non-linear relationship and continuous fluctuations. Despite attempting LocalOutlierFactor, DBSCAN, IsolationForest and PolynomialFeature in scikit-learn, outlier removal remains challenging. Parameter 1 ranges from 0.01 to 0.077, while Parameter 2 ranges from 3 to 12.
Seeking advice on effective outlier removal methods to improve the correlation and better prepare the data for training a random forest regression model. Any insights or experiences would be greatly appreciated.

Do you know if your outliers are intrinsic to the noisy experimental data that you have obtained or due external influences like radio interference spikes from passing taxis? If you show us a graph of your data and the sort of equation you are trying to fit it might be possible to suggest a way of eliminating the worst of the outliers.
